# What tenses work with "all the time"?

Tags: past-tense, adverbial-phrases, progressive-aspect

> I was very lucky the first time I played tennis. I won the first four games and was beginning the fifth when the man I was playing against said with a shouting voice "I stop playing against you. You are winning **all the time**. It is not possible to be so lucky."

In this sentence *all the time* refers to the time I was playing, so progressive should be correct — but if *all the time* referred to a behavior, then would the simple present be better than the progressive one?

Comment: "Said with a shouting voice" = "shouted" or "said loudly".

Answer (score 1):

The *present progressive* is correct here, but not because you were playing at that moment. There's another function of present continuous here, which is to *express annoyance at a repeated event*. It's often used with "always":

> My sister is always borrowing my clothes without asking!

This indicates something that happens regularly, which is normally indicated with *present simple*. But to add a feeling of irritation or annoyance, you can use present progressive.

The man you were playing with was annoyed at something that happened repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

The whole meaning is a bit off.  "All the time" doesn't mean "today", it means "forever".  You have won four matches this morning - does your opponent mean that you have never lost a game and never will?  No, they are saying that you are playing very strongly (or very luckily) today, and present continuous is a good choice, but paired with a different time phrase:

> You're winning everything this morning!

("I stop" is the wrong tense though.)

Comment: yes I will stop is better , thought I chose  future  but did not

Comment: even better is "going to stop" since it is a future that results directly from the present. And in speech, everything would be contracted "I'm gonna stop".. "It's not possible" or "It ain't possible".

Comment: but it is also an instant decision , the opponent did not to plan to stop the match before it is finished

Comment: "Going to" doesn't mean plan.

Comment: Going to tends to be used about events that were previously decided

Comment: @YvesLefol - no, you could make that choice on the spur of the moment. It still indicates a future action, even if that future is only moments away. It's very likely a hyperbolic statement anyway, not meant to be taken literally.

Comment: So I must use going to not will

Comment: Generally "will" and "going to" mean the same and you can use either.  This particular situation does fit "going to" very well.  I think native speakers would use "going to" 99% of the time.